# JSON Traversal in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I currently have JSON from a remote source in this format:

```
{
makemodels: [
{
make: "Abarth ",
model: "500"
},
{
make: "Aixam ",
model: "400"
}]}
```

My issue is my parse does not appear to succeed, even though no errors are thrown i.e. *makeModel_list = json as? NSArray* does not succeed.

```
var parseError: NSError?
let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &parseError)

if (parseError == nil)
            {
                if let makeModel_list = json as? NSArray {
                    NSLog("List %@", makeModel_list)
                }
            }
```

I am hypothesising its to do with the format of my JSON but not matter what I try, I cannot extract the data. I have this working for many years in standard Objective-C. My end goal is to place the data in a NSDictionary with the Key/Pair being Make/Model

Comment: Your top level object is not an array, it's a dictionary with one key `"makemodels"`.

Comment: BTW, I hope that's not really your JSON. It's not valid. Those strings have to be quoted.

Comment: According to JSONLint its valid

Comment: When I run the above JSON through http://jsonlint.con, it says it's not valid. Anyway, the below shows you how to traverse through the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dictionary, whose value for `makemodels` key is, itself, an array of dictionaries. So you can parse it with something like:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? [String : AnyObject] {
    if let makeModels = json["makemodels"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
        for makeModel in makeModels {
            // use it here
        }
    } else {
        println("makemodels not found")
    }
} else {
    println("json parsing failed \(parseError)")
}
```